# What does this Drupal LDAP error mean?

Tags: drupal, ldap, error

**PROBLEM:** Trouble shooting LDAP connection binding and request resolution

**ERROR:** "LDAP Bind failure for user . Error -1: Can't contact LDAP server"

---

**SOLVED** "Authentication with the LDAP server succeeded."

Comment: It would be helpful if you provided a few more details up front.  Vague questions like this are a good way to get down-voted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means it couldn't connect to the LDAP instance you specified.

- Make sure your configuration under *Administer >> Site Configuration >> LDAP Integration* is correct.  You can refer to the documentation [here](http://drupal.org/node/118092).
- Try connecting with an LDAP client like [JXplorer](http://jxplorer.org/) to validate that your LDAP instance is up an running at the host and port you think it is.

If you want a better answer you'll have to provide more details.

Comment: **@BenV:** What information would be of use? I've looked at 100s of pages related to it, tried lots of stuff. If you read the comments on the page you linked to, you'll notice a common theme... the documentation is superbad, if not plain wrong. I've tried coding a basic LDAP connection by hand in PHP, but couldn't get it to work (as a control test)... here's the post on that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3993128/how-do-i-test-ldap-configs-with-php happy to answer ANY and All questions, just can't believe someone would take the time to code something like this and not have feedback test.

Comment: @blunders: From http://tinyurl.com/so-hints: What did you expect it to do? What are you trying to accomplish? What have you already tried? What happened in those attempts? Be detailed: in particular, if something didn't work, don't just state that: tell us how it failed. If it threw an exception, what was the exception? (Don't just give the type - give the error message and say which line threw it. If there's a nested exception, post that too.)

Comment: @blunders: see updates in my answer above.

Comment: **@BenV:** Posted some more info, not sure if it's of any use.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is the same problem you're having, but you might look at this:
http://drupal.org/node/99009

Comment: **@Adam Thompson:** Thanks, and yes, I've seen that page. In some cases, OpenLDAP 2.3+ (I believe) it requires a SSL-CERT by default, "TLS_REQCERT never" turns that requirement off. I've tried that, but received the same error. Do believe both Apache and PHP are working right, but super hard to tell... :-)